# Почему не работает 301-й редирект с HTTP на HTTPS?

Tags: .htaccess, https, redirect

В .htaccess прописан редирект:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =of
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

однако, при обращении к сайту по http редиректа на https не происходит.

В чем еще может быть причина?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Может `=off`, не `=of`?

Comment: Исправил на off и получаю бесконечный редирект.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Или так:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: В обоих случаях редирект происходит, но добавляется 80-й порт.

Comment: @gubin а вам какой нужен порт? 443?

Comment: Да, но почему-то автоматом добавляется 80-й. "Ошибка при установлении защищённого соединения

При соединении с site.com:80 произошла ошибка. SSL получило запись, длина которой превышает максимально допустимую. Код ошибки: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG

    Страница, которую вы пытаетесь просмотреть, не может быть отображена, так как достоверность полученных данных не может быть проверена.
    Пожалуйста, свяжитесь с владельцами веб-сайта и проинформируйте их об этой проблеме."

Comment: @gubin смотрите настройки сервера или пишите хосту, что-то не так настроено у вас.

Comment: Спасибо, будем смотреть настройки сервера

Comment: @gubin ну мой пример работает в 99% случаев верно. Всегда их использую.